# PPST request is working as GET Request in Globiflow

Tags: http, curl, podio

I am trying to send the message from Globiflow through **REST POST API** but it works as **GET request**. It gets all SMS history from my account as the response.

[image: Globiflow Code]

Please guide me how can I use that API as POST.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the "+" with "%2B"